# Jasper IReport 4.5.1 - How to fix the position of components of Ireport eg "static text" or "text field"

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I want to design a template/report where certain component's position become static or frozen. Anyone using my jrxml file, should not be able to re-position it at design time. He can add/delete new fields, but cannot modify components I have frozen.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

No. The .jrxml is just a text file (an XML file). There is no feature for locking it down in iReport.

You can achieve functionality like this by abstracting the user from the .jrxml. For example in JasperReports Server you can let the user layout the report, but the server always places some fixed things into the final report.